# How to use toLowerCase() function before filter?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-effect

[image]

I want to lowercase product.productName before filter, but I couldn't do that. I tried some thing but didn't work. Is there any way that I can lowercase product.productName before filter?

Comment: _"I tried some thing but didn't work"_ What did you try? What happened exactly?

Comment: Why cant u use `.toLowerCase()` e.g. `product.productName.toLowerCase().includes ....` ?

Comment: I was trying foreach before filter... @kmoser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply convert to lowercase inside filter before comparing.
e.g.
`product.productName.toLowerCase().includes ....`.

If it complains about being an object, convert to string first.

`product.productName.toString().toLowerCase().includes ....`

Answer (score 1):

`.map()` could be used as a step before `filter()`

```
products
  .map(product => product.productName.toLowerCase())
  .filter(...)
```